# why am i getting this big number error. I have tried everything but cannot figure it out

Tags: uniswap, ethereumjs, uniswapv3, etherjs

I am trying to run the scripts for uniswap V3. I am able to mint the positions and check the position but I cannot increase or decrease the liquidity by calling these functions. I get the following error:

```
    Error: invalid BigNumber value (argument="value", value=undefined, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bignumber/5.7.0)
        at Logger.makeError (C:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Documents\OptimusFox\hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:269:28)
        at Logger.throwError (C:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Documents\OptimusFox\hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:281:20)
        at Logger.throwArgumentError (C:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Documents\OptimusFox\hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\logger\src.ts\index.ts:285:21)
        at Function.BigNumber.from (C:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Documents\OptimusFox\hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\bignumber\src.ts\bignumber.ts:289:23)
        at NumberCoder.encode (C:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Documents\OptimusFox\hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\number.ts:25:27)
        at C:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Documents\OptimusFox\hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\array.ts:71:19
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at pack (C:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Documents\OptimusFox\hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\array.ts:54:12)
        at TupleCoder.encode (C:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Documents\OptimusFox\hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\tuple.ts:54:20)
        at C:\Users\moham\OneDrive\Documents\OptimusFox\hardhat\node_modules\@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\coders\array.ts:71:19 {
      reason: 'invalid BigNumber value',
      code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
      argument: 'value',
      value: undefined
```

here is my script

```
    // Uniswap contract addresses
    WETH_ADDRESS= '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3'
    FACTORY_ADDRESS= '0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512'
    SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS= '0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0'
    NFT_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS= '0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9'
    POSITION_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS= '0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9'
    POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS= '0x5FC8d32690cc91D4c39d9d3abcBD16989F875707'
    
    // Pool addresses
    USDT_USDC_500= '0x1FA8DDa81477A5b6FA1b2e149e93ed9C7928992F'
    
    // Token addresses
    TETHER_ADDRESS= '0x0165878A594ca255338adfa4d48449f69242Eb8F'
    USDC_ADDRESS= '0xa513E6E4b8f2a923D98304ec87F64353C4D5C853'
    WRAPPED_BITCOIN_ADDRESS= '0x2279B7A0a67DB372996a5FaB50D91eAA73d2eBe6'
    
    const artifacts = {
      NonfungiblePositionManager: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol/NonfungiblePositionManager.json"),
      Usdt: require("../artifacts/contracts/Tether.sol/Tether.json"),
      Usdc: require("../artifacts/contracts/UsdCoin.sol/UsdCoin.json"),
      UniswapV3Pool: require("@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol/UniswapV3Pool.json"),
    };
    
    const { Contract } = require("ethers")
    const { Token } = require('@uniswap/sdk-core')
    const { Pool, Position, nearestUsableTick } = require('@uniswap/v3-sdk')
    const { ethers } = require("hardhat")
    
    async function getPoolData(poolContract) {
      const [tickSpacing, fee, liquidity, slot0] = await Promise.all([
        poolContract.tickSpacing(),
        poolContract.fee(),
        poolContract.liquidity(),
        poolContract.slot0(),
      ])
      // console.log("Tick Spacing", await poolContract.tickSpacing() )
      // console.log("Fee",await poolContract.fee())
      // console.log("Liquidity", await poolContract.liquidity())
      // console.log("Slot 0",await poolContract.slot0() )
    
      return {
        tickSpacing: tickSpacing,
        fee: fee,
        liquidity: liquidity,
        sqrtPriceX96: slot0[0],
        tick: slot0[1],
      }
    }
    
    async function main() {
      const [owner, signer2] = await ethers.getSigners();
      const provider = waffle.provider;
    
      const usdtContract = new Contract(TETHER_ADDRESS,artifacts.Usdt.abi,provider)
      const usdcContract = new Contract(USDC_ADDRESS,artifacts.Usdc.abi,provider)
    
      await usdtContract.connect(signer2).approve(POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS, ethers.utils.parseEther('1000'))
      await usdcContract.connect(signer2).approve(POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS, ethers.utils.parseEther('1000'))
    
      const poolContract = new Contract(USDT_USDC_500, artifacts.UniswapV3Pool.abi, provider)
    
      const poolData = await getPoolData(poolContract)
      // console.log("POOL DATA", poolData);
    
      const UsdtToken = new Token(31337, TETHER_ADDRESS, 18, 'USDT', 'Tether')
      const UsdcToken = new Token(31337, USDC_ADDRESS, 18, 'USDC', 'UsdCoin')
    
      const pool = new Pool(
        UsdtToken,
        UsdcToken,
        poolData.fee,
        poolData.sqrtPriceX96.toString(),
        poolData.liquidity.toString(),
        poolData.tick
      )
    
      const position = new Position({
        pool: pool,
        liquidity: ethers.utils.parseEther('1'),
        tickLower: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) - poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
        tickUpper: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) + poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
      })
    
      const { amount0: amount0Desired, amount1: amount1Desired} = position.mintAmounts
    
      params = {
        token0: TETHER_ADDRESS,
        token1: USDC_ADDRESS,
        fee: poolData.fee,
        tickLower: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) - poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
        tickUpper: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) + poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
        amount0Desired: amount0Desired.toString(),
        amount1Desired: amount1Desired.toString(),
        amount0Min: 0,
        amount1Min: 0,
        recipient: signer2.address,
        deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 10)
      }
    
      const nonfungiblePositionManager = new ethers.Contract(
        POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS,
        artifacts.NonfungiblePositionManager.abi,
        provider
      )
    
      const tx = await nonfungiblePositionManager.connect(signer2).mint(
        params,
        { gasLimit: '1000000' }
      )
    
    
      const receipt = await tx.wait()
      const event1 = await receipt.events[6];
      // console.log("EVENT1-----------", event1)
      let value = event1.args[0]
      let value1 = event1.args[1] - 10000
      let value2 = event1.args[2]- 10000
      let value3 = event1.args[3]- 10000
      console.log("VALUE---------", value)
      console.log("VALUE1---------", value1)
      console.log("VALUE-2--------", value2)
      console.log("VALUE--3-------", value3)
    
      const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) + (60 * 10)
      const increaseLiquidity_ = await nonfungiblePositionManager.connect(signer2).increaseLiquidity(
        {value,
        value1,
        value2 ,
        value3,
        deadline}, 
        {gasLimit: '10000000000'}
      )
      
    
    }
    
    /*
    npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/04_addLiquidity.js
    */
    
    main()
      .then(() => process.exit(0))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
        process.exit(1);
      });
```

My addLiquidity script:

```
// Uniswap contract addresses
WETH_ADDRESS= '0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3'
FACTORY_ADDRESS= '0xe7f1725E7734CE288F8367e1Bb143E90bb3F0512'
SWAP_ROUTER_ADDRESS= '0x9fE46736679d2D9a65F0992F2272dE9f3c7fa6e0'
NFT_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS= '0xCf7Ed3AccA5a467e9e704C703E8D87F634fB0Fc9'
POSITION_DESCRIPTOR_ADDRESS= '0xDc64a140Aa3E981100a9becA4E685f962f0cF6C9'
POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS= '0x5FC8d32690cc91D4c39d9d3abcBD16989F875707'

// Pool addresses
USDT_USDC_500= '0x1FA8DDa81477A5b6FA1b2e149e93ed9C7928992F'

// Token addresses
TETHER_ADDRESS= '0x0165878A594ca255338adfa4d48449f69242Eb8F'
USDC_ADDRESS= '0xa513E6E4b8f2a923D98304ec87F64353C4D5C853'
WRAPPED_BITCOIN_ADDRESS= '0x2279B7A0a67DB372996a5FaB50D91eAA73d2eBe6'

const artifacts = {
  NonfungiblePositionManager: require("@uniswap/v3-periphery/artifacts/contracts/NonfungiblePositionManager.sol/NonfungiblePositionManager.json"),
  Usdt: require("../artifacts/contracts/Tether.sol/Tether.json"),
  Usdc: require("../artifacts/contracts/UsdCoin.sol/UsdCoin.json"),
  UniswapV3Pool: require("@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/UniswapV3Pool.sol/UniswapV3Pool.json"),
};


const { Contract } = require("ethers")
const { Token } = require('@uniswap/sdk-core')
const { Pool, Position, nearestUsableTick } = require('@uniswap/v3-sdk')
const { ethers } = require("hardhat")

async function getPoolData(poolContract) {
  const [tickSpacing, fee, liquidity, slot0] = await Promise.all([
    poolContract.tickSpacing(),
    poolContract.fee(),
    poolContract.liquidity(),
    poolContract.slot0(),
  ])
  console.log("HERE")
  // console.log("Tick Spacing", await poolContract.tickSpacing() )
  // console.log("Fee",await poolContract.fee())
  // console.log("Liquidity", await poolContract.liquidity())
  // console.log("Slot 0",await poolContract.slot0() )

  return {
    tickSpacing: tickSpacing,
    fee: fee,
    liquidity: liquidity,
    sqrtPriceX96: slot0[0],
    tick: slot0[1],
  }
}

async function main() {
  console.log("here")
  console.log(ethers)
  const owner = await ethers.getSigners();
  
  const provider = waffle.provider;
  
  const usdtContract = new Contract(TETHER_ADDRESS,artifacts.Usdt.abi,provider)
  const usdcContract = new Contract(USDC_ADDRESS,artifacts.Usdc.abi,provider)
  
  await usdtContract.connect(signer2).approve(POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS, ethers.utils.parseEther('1000'))
  await usdcContract.connect(signer2).approve(POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS, ethers.utils.parseEther('1000'))

  const poolContract = new Contract(USDT_USDC_500, artifacts.UniswapV3Pool.abi, provider)

  const poolData = await getPoolData(poolContract)
  // console.log("POOL DATA", poolData);
  
  const UsdtToken = new Token(31337, TETHER_ADDRESS, 18, 'USDT', 'Tether')
  const UsdcToken = new Token(31337, USDC_ADDRESS, 18, 'USDC', 'UsdCoin')

  const pool = new Pool(
    UsdtToken,
    UsdcToken,
    poolData.fee,
    poolData.sqrtPriceX96.toString(),
    poolData.liquidity.toString(),
    poolData.tick
  )

  const position = new Position({
    pool: pool,
    liquidity: ethers.utils.parseEther('1'),
    tickLower: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) - poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
    tickUpper: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) + poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
  })

  const { amount0: amount0Desired, amount1: amount1Desired} = position.mintAmounts

  params = {
    token0: TETHER_ADDRESS,
    token1: USDC_ADDRESS,
    fee: poolData.fee,
    tickLower: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) - poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
    tickUpper: nearestUsableTick(poolData.tick, poolData.tickSpacing) + poolData.tickSpacing * 2,
    amount0Desired: amount0Desired.toString(),
    amount1Desired: amount1Desired.toString(),
    amount0Min: 0,
    amount1Min: 0,
    recipient: signer2.address,
    deadline: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + (60 * 10)
  }

  const nonfungiblePositionManager = new ethers.Contract(
    POSITION_MANAGER_ADDRESS,
    artifacts.NonfungiblePositionManager.abi,
    provider
  )

  const tx = await nonfungiblePositionManager.connect(signer2).mint(
    params,
    { gasLimit: '1000000' }
  )


  const receipt = await tx.wait()
  const event1 = await receipt.events[6];
  // console.log("EVENT1-----------", event1)
  let value = event1.args[0]
  let value1 = event1.args[1] - 10000
  let value2 = event1.args[2]- 10000
  let value3 = event1.args[3]- 10000
  console.log("VALUE---------", value)
  console.log("VALUE1---------", value1)
  console.log("VALUE-2--------", value2)
  console.log("VALUE--3-------", value3)

  const deadline = Math.floor(Date.now()/1000) + (60 * 10)
  const increaseLiquidity_ = await nonfungiblePositionManager.connect(signer2).decreaseLiquidity(
    {value,
    value1,
    value2 ,
    value3,
    deadline}, 
    {gasLimit: '10000000000'}
  )
  // console.log("receipt", receipt)
  // nonfungiblePositionManager.on("IncreaseLiquidity", (tokenId, liquidity, amount0, amount1) =>{
  //   console.log("JEREREE")
  // let info ={
  //   tokenId: tokenId,
  //   liquidity: liquidity,
  //   amount0: ethers.utils.formatEther(amount0, 6),
  //   amount1: ethers.utils.formatEther(amount1, 6)
  // };
  // console.log("HERE",JSON.stringify(info, null, 4));
// })

}

/*
npx hardhat run --network localhost scripts/04_addLiquidity.js
*/

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

Comment: can you post your `04_addLiquidity.js` file?

Comment: Added. can you have a look at it, please?

Comment: @Nunce.ether Usually, that error means a variable wasn't initialized properly. Check if the returned data matches the way it is being used.